# Karma Test: PhantomJS: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Pusher

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, phantomjs

I'm writing some unit tests, in my AngularJS controller I'm using Pusher for asynchronous connections.

```
  var DriverCtrl,
    scope;

  var $httpBackend = {};

  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, _$httpBackend_, _DriverService_, _PusherService_, _AuthService_) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    DriverCtrl = $controller('DriverCtrl', {
      $scope: scope,
      DriverService: _DriverService_,
      PusherService: _PusherService_,
      AuthService: _AuthService_
    });
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
  }));

  afterEach(function () {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });
```

First I was getting following exception after going through the pusher documentation, I made changes to my karma.conf.js and bower.json

```
 PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux) DriverCtrl should be connected to driver view FAILED
            ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Pusher
```

karma.conf.js, I've added this line

```
'bower_components/angular-scenario/angular-scenario.js'
```

and to bower.json. I've this section

```
"devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.2.0",
    "angular-scenario": "~1.2.0",
    "pusher-test-stub": "*"
  }
```

Now I'm getting following error

```
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/home/machine/RubyProjects/TaxiTeam4/taxihome-frontend/test/mock/**/*.js" does not match any file.
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux)]: Connected on socket imIXyLQV7jW3QeXo0W5c with id 33183997
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.001 secs / 0 secs)
Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

I've tried changing ports in karma.conf.js didn't help

Comment: May I ask you question/ You are trying to write a unit-test, but you include angular-scenario which is e2e tests. You just can mock your services which are used in your controller.

Comment: Also, look at this https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js-test-stub/tree/master/examples
There are no unit tests, only e2e tests